# VS-Code Extension does not create files after VSIX build

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've developed an extension for VS-Code, that is supposed to create new Files based on certain contents of the current VS-Code editor.
Everything works great and without a problem, but after i create a VSIX file, the extension does not generate files when i use it outside the development projekt.

Below is the code that is meant to create new files

```
var enumFileName = 'Enum' + NextNo + '.' + 'PTE' + selectedOptionFields[i]['FieldName'].replace('_', '').replace(/"/g,"");
var enumFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'converted-enums', `${enumFileName}.al`);
let enumFolderDirectory = path.dirname(enumFilePath);

if (!FileSystem.existsSync(enumFolderDirectory)) {
FileSystem.mkdirSync(enumFolderDirectory, { recursive: true });}

FileSystem.writeFile(enumFilePath, enumContent, (err) => {
if (err) throw err;});
};
```

I know the extension is active and works, because my command still opens a multi pick selection window and the active editor gets modified.
But the most important part of my extension, the file generation based on certain values of the active editor, does not work anymore.

This is my very first extension, but i made sure that all of my dependencies are entered in the package.json and the vscode-ignore file does not include any important filepath.

Since i cant debug the extension while it's installed, i have no idea why this bug is occuring. Any ideas would be appreceated.

Comment: you can debug the extension, add `console.log` statements, why don't you use `vscode.workspace.fs` it also supports remote workspaces

Comment: why don't you use `writeFileSync`

Comment: I am currently trying to debug with console.log, but there seems to be no output whatsoever. I put several logs bevor the multi pick logik, because i know its going to be executed. But there is nothing showing up in my vscode console. And what exactly does vscode.workspace.fs do?

Comment: `vscode.workspace.fs` is similar to NodeJS `fs` but it knows remote URI's, where are you looking for the `console.log` output

Comment: I have tried to use vscode.workspace.fs method, but the result was the same. I am looking at the "Output" and "Debug Console" tab but can't find any logs there. I assume this is not the right place? Addionaly, i have found that  there is a runtime status for each extension, that also shows you errors. In my Case the runtime status displays "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')". But i am helpless without knowing where this errror occurs exactly

Comment: where do you look for `console.log` statements in the Browser? `Debug Console` is for the output of the debugger  for the programs you debug not for the editor

Comment: I dont really understand what you are asking for to be honest. I developed the Extension in VS-Code by using node.js as a runtime environment. What has this to to with my browser (Sorry, am not experienced with this kind of development)

Comment: VSC is Google Chrome is disguise, Where do you look for `console.log` statement output in a browser, you have that to in VSC, look for it in all the menus

Comment: @Liam, No this is a totally unrelated topic. Thanks though

Comment: @rioV8 Im not sure how VSC is related to google chrome in any way, but as i previously said: I checked the terminal, output and debug console for console logs, but there are non generated. There are no other locations in VSC where logs could appear. Thanks for your help, but i don't think this approach is leading me anywhere. I'll try to achieve my goal in another way.

Comment: **look for it in all the menus**, you clearly haven't done that, VSC is build on Electron and Electron is Google Chrome, VSC is rendering the whole UI as a web page. Thus VSC is a browser only it renders a specific type of web page

Comment: `terminal, output and debug console`, and I told you you will not find it there

Comment: When you run your extension (your VSIX version), open the Help/Toggle Developer Tools and then look in the Developer Tools Console.  Your console.log's should be there.  As for "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')" - this means that whatever is calling its `length` property is undefined.  So do you have a `xxxx.length` call somewhere in your code?  Apparently the `xxxx` object is undefined when your code gets to that line.